# simple multi-threading in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I've created a simple python program that scrapes my favorite recipe website and returns the individual recipe URLs from the main site. While this is a relatively quick and simple process, I've tried scaling this out to scrape multiple webpages within the site. When I do this, it takes about 45 seconds to scrape all of the recipe URLs from the whole site. I'd like this process to be much quicker so I tried implementing threads into my program.

I realize there is something wrong here as each thread returns the whole URL thread over and over again instead of 'splitting up' the work. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to better implement the threads? I've included my work below. Using Python 3.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
from datetime import datetime
import threading

from datetime import datetime

startTime = datetime.now()

quote_page='http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking_cat/all-pw-recipes/'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

all_recipe_links = []

#get all recipe links on current page
def get_recipe_links():
    for link in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'post-card-permalink'}):
        if link.has_attr('href'):
            if 'cooking/' in link.attrs['href']:
                all_recipe_links.append(link.attrs['href'])

    print(datetime.now() - startTime)
    return all_recipe_links


def worker():
    """thread worker function"""
    print(get_recipe_links())
    return

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

Comment: Your worker threads just try to scrape the `quote_page` all over again. What do you mean by splitting up the work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to distribute the work to the workers by having the workers all process data from a single list, instead of having them all run the whole method individually. Below are the parts that I changed. The method `get_recipe_links` is no longer needed, since its tasks have been moved to other methods.

```
all_recipe_links = []
links_to_process = []

def worker():
    """thread worker function"""
    while(len(links_to_process) > 0):
        link = links_to_process.pop()
        if link.has_attr('href'):
                if 'cooking/' in link.attrs['href']:
                    all_recipe_links.append(link.attrs['href'])        

threads = []
links_to_process = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'post-card-permalink'})
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

while len(links_to_process)>0:
    continue
print(all_recipe_links)
```

I ran the new methods several times, and on average it takes .02 seconds to run this.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked like a charm. I appreciate you taking the time to help me!